GitLab CI/CD anchor links
I have a pipeline, I want to optimize it. Is it possible to use this type of links in CI? When using anchor links, I always get a syntax error
jobs:describe_version:rules:rule if invalid expression syntax

I can't figure out the syntax, is this option supported or not?
.default_rules:
  rules:
    # master branch engaged
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH'
      when: always
    # version tag engaged
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^(v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?$/'
      when: always
    # triggered manually from web
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE =~ /^web/'
      when: always

.default_condition: &default_condition
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^(v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?$/ || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE =~ /^web/'

.job_rules:
  default:
    - if: *default_condition
  prego:
    - if: '(*default_condition) && $PREGO_BUILD =~ /true/i'
  checkouts:
    - if: '(*default_condition) && $CHECKOUTS_GROUP =~ /^./'
  pubdocs:
    - if: '(*default_condition) && ($PUBLIC_DOCS_GROUP =~ /^./ || $PUBLIC_DOCS_LINKS =~ /^./)'
  redmine:
    - if: '$REDMINE_FETCH_REPO =~ /^./'


describe_version:
  stage: describe
  image: bitnami/git:latest
  rules:
    - !reference [.job_rules, default]

What am I doing wrong?
